# cannot install the spatie package to laravel 8 application

Tags: laravel-8

i try to install the spatie package to my laravel 8 application with php 8.0.3 but I got this error:
[InvalidArgumentException]
Package spatie/laravel-medialibrary at version ^8.0.0 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP
extensions and Composer version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the package developers didn't update the medialibrary 8.x.x to accommodate support for PHP8, until this changes, you can always migrate to version 9.x via editing your composer.json and running `composer update` (Look for `laravel-medialibrary` and change it to be like this):

```
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^9.0.0",
```